# (Analysis I by Tao - Exercise 2.2.5) Please review my proposed proof of the strong principle of inducction.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to work through Analysis I by Tao (4th Edition). I wanted to post my (proposed) solution to Problem 2.2.5 and see if I made any serious errors. Throughout, I use the notation $n^+$ to mean the successor of $n$, so that $n^+=S(n) = n+1$.

I apologize if some variables (like $m$) are reused in multiple spots in the proof. I hope that it doesn't cause any confusion. I should probably break up the proof using several propositions.

Theorem: Let $m_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $P(m)$ be a property pertaining to an arbitrary natural number $m$. Assume that, for all $m\geq m_0$, $P(m)$ is such that if $P(m')$ is true for all natural numbers $m_0 \leq m' < m$, then $P(m)$ is true. It follows that $P(m)$ is true for all natural numbers $m \geq m_0$.

Proof: define $Q(n)$ to be the statement that:

for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m_0 \leq m < n, P(m)$ is true

There is an equivalency between proving that $Q(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and proving that $P(m)$ is true for all $m \geq m_0$ (which is the desired result). In particular, if $Q(n)$ is true for all $n$, then $Q(m^+)$ is also true, which states that:

for all $m'\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m_0 \leq m' < m^+, P(m')$ is true

Now, assume that $m \geq m_0$. $m$ is less than $m^+$ (since $m^+=m+1$ and $m \neq m^+$), so that $m_0 \leq m < m^+$, and thus, $P(m)$ is true by the statement of $Q(m^+)$ above.

To prove that $Q(n)$ is true for all $n$, it suffices to prove that $Q(0)$ and $Q(n) \to Q(n^+)$ are both true (by Axiom 2.5). We proceed by induction on $n$.

Consider the base case in which $n=0$. $Q(0)$ states that for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m_0 \leq m < 0, P(m)$ is true

No such $m$ exists, so that $Q(0)$ is vacuously true. To see why no such $m$ exists, proceed by contradiction and assume that $m<0$. This implies that $0=m+x_1$ for some natural number $x_1$ and that $m \neq 0$. By Corollary 2.2.9, $m=0$, which is a contradiction.

Now, the goal is to prove that $Q(n^+)$ is true, which states that:

for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m_0 \leq m < n^+, P(m)$ is true

assuming that $Q(n)$ is true, which again, states that:

for all $m'\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m_0 \leq m' < n, P(m')$ is true

To prove $Q(n^+)$, assume that $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m_0 \leq m <n^+$, with the goal of proving that $P(m)$ is always true. By the trichotomy property of the natural numbers (Proposition 2.2.13), either $m<n$, $m=n$, or $m>n$, and only one can apply at once.

Case 1 ($m<n$): by assumption, $m_0 \leq m < n$, so that $m$ is a natural number that matches the requirements of the induction hypothesis, from which it follows that $P(m)$ is true.

Case 2 ($m=n$): assume that the induction hypothesis is true. Since $P(m')$ is true for all $m_0 \leq m' < n$, it follows from the assumed properties of $P$ that $P(n)$ is true. Since $m=n$, it follows that $P(m)$ is true as well.

Case 3 ($m>n$): Assume that $n<m$ and $m<n^+$. By Proposition 2.2.12E, $n<m$ implies that $m \geq n^+$, which implies that either $m>n^+$ or $m=n^+$. By the trichotomy property of the natural numbers (Proposition 2.2.13), $m<n^+$ is imcompatible with the previous statement. Thus, no such natural number $m$ exists.

Thus, for all $m$ under consideration ($m_0 \leq m < n^+$), $m$ satisfies either Case 1 or Case 2, in which $P(m)$ is true. Thus, $P(m)$ is true, which implies that $Q(n^+)$ is true, which closes the induction.

Comment: Just an initial thought: don't you need $P(m_0)$ to be true by assumption for the theorem to hold?

Comment: @AksharaPrasad Hi! Since I'm doing induction on $Q(n)$ rather than $P(m)$, does $P(m_0)$ have to be proven explicitly?